# ¿Cómo hacer que un modelo siempre tenga una clase extendida en Codeigniter 4 con php spark?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-4, spark

Hola tengo un problema que no logro solucionar.

Uso por ejm el comando

```
php spark make:model Sidebars
```

Para crear mis modelos en Codeigniter4,

El problema es que se me crean de esta manera con la clase extends **Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class SidebarsModel extends Model
```

y yo necesito que siempre se me creen con otra clase extendida **BaseModel** como esta:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class SidebarsModel extends BaseModel
```

No logro ubicar que archivos debo modificar para que el comando funcione asi tal cual.

Pueden ayudarme por favor.

Gracias